# Linux "find -regex" doesn't handle binding

Tags: linux, find, regex

I have the following files, and need to match them like:

```
./foo.bar1.sh       -match

./qux/foo.bar2.sh   -match

./foo.sh            -match

./baz.sh            -no match

./foo.bar3          -no match
```

I have tried:

```
find . -regex ".*foo(bar[0-9])?\.sh"
```

But it returns nothing. I cannot figure out why that regex won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression has two errors:

1. It misses a (literal) dot after `foo`.
2. `find` requires you to escape the parentheses when **not** used as literal parentheses.

Also, you should escape the dot before `sh`, since it will match any character.

The fixed command now reads:

```
find . -regex ".*foo\(\.bar[0-9]\)?\.sh"
```

Error 2., by the way, is the reason why I don't like `find`'s `-regex` switch: Inconsistent escaping.

It works, of course, but `grep -P` uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE), so there are more features, but less surprises and pitfalls.

Personally, I'd use:

```
find . | grep -P "foo(\.bar\d)?\.sh"
```